# Clickable button with drop down

Tags: java, eclipse, drop-down-menu, eclipse-plugin, dropdown

I'm trying to create a button that has a drop down menu and clickable. 
How would I do this when developing for eclipse plugin? 
I'm looking for answers that are specific to Eclipse Plugin development if possible. Preferably without xmls, only java code.

Searched and checked eclipse documentation but didn't find a reachable answer for button performing both. Would  appreciate a link to online example (guessing it exists).

I want the button to behave like Debug\Run\New icon buttons: Clickable with Dropdown at the side.

[image]

Comment: There is some information [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Dropdown_Command)

Comment: @greg-449 thank for the info but I already saw it and its not what I'm looking for. I need a java based solution as I'm trying to get rid of those horrible xmls...

Comment: The extension point XML is the correct way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a roundabout solution myself in the end.
Here is an example:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
....
              //These 3 lines are the solution for style, turns out to be simple.
                Image image = <<Your image for deselected>>;
                ToolItem item = = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.BEGINNING | SWT.DROP_DOWN);
                item.setImage(image);
              //Menu creation for arrow
                Menu menu = new Menu(item.getParent().getShell());
                new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH).setText("Menu item example 1");
              //Indication for state of button press (to give it checkbox behavior - does not have to be atomic)
                AtomicBoolean recording = new AtomicBoolean(false);
              //This is where the logic is for opening the menu and enabling a checkbox behavior 
              //is done. ((width * 3) was added because tool bar is on the side for my specific use case)
                item.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> {
                                if (e.detail == SWT.ARROW) {
                                    Rectangle rect = item.getBounds();
                                    Point pt = new Point(rect.x - (rect.width * 3), rect.y + rect.height);
                                    pt = toolBar.toDisplay(pt);
                                    menu.setLocation(pt.x, pt.y);
                                    menu.setVisible(true);
                                } else {
                                   //logic for pressing icon. You can swap the icon 
                                   //image according to needed with item.setImage()
                                }
                            });
```